# How to Create a MySQL Table with the Primary Key sorted by DESC and keep it that way after INSERTing new rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, primary-key

I need to create an `InnoDB` table that I will use to add data to and constantly fetch the **most recent** 10 rows added to it.  To avoid having to do an `ORDER BY` with *every* `SELECT` query to get those last 10 rows, I would like to have the table itself ordered by the `Primary Key` in `DESC` order so that I can skip the `ORDER BY` entirely and just do a `SELECT ... LIMIT 10`, which should automatically pull the most recent 10 rows added to the table.

How can I do that?  Is it as simple as adding `ORDER BY [PRIMARYKEY] DESC` to the `CREATE TABLE` query?  Will the table **continue** to be sorted in `DESC` order even after `INSERT`ing new rows?

Comment: Rows in a relational database table do ***NOT*** have an order. The **only** way to ensure a specific order is to use an `ORDER BY`. There is no other option.

Comment: You could use a stored procedure to automatically run the query, but its so simple thats unneeded complexity. Just use the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: How about ordering the Primary Key Index by `DESC` to speed up the `ORDER BY`?  Is that doable in MySQL **5.5**?

Comment: No. MySQL does not support a direction when creating an index (it is accepted by silently ignored like so many other things in MySQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: OK, so if you can't sort the table by the Primary Key `DESC` OR the Primary Key index by `DESC`, then is there **any** way to speed up the fetching of the latest rows other than just doing a straight `ORDER BY [PRIMARYKEY] DESC` ?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RDBMS never provides any guarantees on the order of the rows in any of the tables it manages. The only way to get a specific order is to ask for one. For the case of MySQL, the rows happens to be sorted by the primary key in ascending order often time when that key is in auto increment mode, but it's not a guaranteed property.

Use `ORDER BY` on your queries to get the desired result.

On the other hand, the ordering will be faster if the primary key type is BTREE (which is the default on most engine).

The sorting direction [isn't yet used on MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html).

Comment: What about ordering the Primary Key Index by `DESC` to speed up the `ORDER BY [PRIMARYKEY] DESC`?  Is that doable in MySQL **5.5**?

Comment: OK, so if you can't sort the table by the Primary Key `DESC` OR the Primary Key index by `DESC`, then is there **any** way to speed up the fetching of the latest rows other than just doing a straight `ORDER BY [PRIMARYKEY] DESC` ?

Comment: In order to know if really there's a speed up to obtain, I suggest comparing with the same query in opposite order (ie. try ASC and DESC and compare). If the difference is not significant, there's nothing to gain on this front.